# How to call IsDialogMessage in a Modal Dialog

Tags: winapi, dialog, nested, modal-dialog, modeless

In my Win32 app, I had a modal dialog that displays settings that I had to add more settings to. In order to fit the new settings, I dropped a TabCtrl in the dialog and implemented two modeless dialogs.  The UI is working switching between them but the modeless dialogs don't respond to the keyboard.  In a regular app, IsDialogMessage (hWndCurModelessDialog) would be called.  How would I do this for my Modal dialog containing a modeless dialog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont. The modal dialog box function calls IsDialogMessage from its own message loop automatically.

The modeless dialogs are the 'pages' ? Make sure they are parented to the main dialog (rather than the tab control) and have the DS_CONTROL style. This style allows IsDialogMessage to recurse into a child dialogs controls when tabbing.

Comment: the DS_CONTROL Flag (Control setting in Visual Studio Dialog Settings) did the trick.  Thanks!